# iOS 6 Storyboard UITableView in navigation stack does not Animate back

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController. I am only using Storyboards in iOS 6. When I tap on my Reports Row, I get a nice Push animation to the right. When I press the Auto Generated Back button, my navigation heading fades and animates to the left, but my UITableView just suddenly appears. My goal is to have the UITableview have a standard push animation back like is standard when the back button is pressed. Hopefully this is the relevant code needed to help me debug. I am at a complete loss. I see the same behavior on every one of my views I drill down into when I navigate back up the Navigation tree. They are all UITableViewController subclasses.

I am unable to post a picture of my Storyboard until I have some more reputation points. I can e-mail someone a picture of it if needed to help see the hierarchy.

My Storyboard Hierarchy is:

```
UITabviewController
-UINavigationViewController
--ReportsVC
---AvaliableEquipmentVC
----AvaliableEquipmentDetailVC
```

**ReportsVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ReportsVC : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *reportList;
@end
```

**ReportsVC.m**

```
#import "ReportsVC.h"
#import "AvaliableEquipment.h"

@interface ReportsVC ()

@end

@implementation ReportsVC

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.reportList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // List Reports Here
    [self.reportList addObject:@"Avaliable Equipment"];
    [self.reportList addObject:@"Active Lease Business"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.reportList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReportNameCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *reportTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    NSString *text = [self.reportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    reportTitle.text = text;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AvaliableEquipment" sender:nil]; break;
        case 1: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ActiveLeaseBusiness" sender:nil]; break;
    }
}
```

In my AvaliableEquipmentVC, I don't do anything special except query a JSON list to get my TableView Data. When I press the back button that is auto generated via the storyboard I get no animation back to the UITableViewController ReportsVC.

Comment: You can email me a picture and I'll have a look. rdelmar@comcast.net

Comment: Just sent it. Thanks for taking a look...

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything wrong there (from what I can see). If you can send me the whole project, I could probably tell a lot more.

Comment: OK... I will need to strip out some URL code tomorrow before I can do that. If I can't figure it out by tomorrow afternoon, I will send it your way. Thanks again for taking the time to look...

Answer (score 1):

OK, found out what was wrong for me. In my TableViewController that was my top most object, I had a (void)viewWillAppear as well as a (void)viewDidAppear Method. In those methods I had to add [super viewWillAppear:animated]; as well as [super viewDidAppear:animated]; lines to each of them. This caused the animations to start working again. I had forgotten I overwrote those to do some custom logic.